# SQL Query for finding the least difference of a column value with a constant number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have  a table like this :

```
id  name  value
---------------    
1   one   20
2   two   30
```

and I want to write a query to find the row which it's value has the least absolute difference with constant number 28.

How should I do this?!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your desired output.

Comment: "SELECT * FROM table WHERE value IN (SELECT MIN(ABS(value-'28')) FROM table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution should offer a good performance if there is an index on [Value] column:

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON;

IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.MyDemoTable') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE dbo.MyDemoTable;
END
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.MyDemoTable (
    ID      INT IDENTITY(2,2) PRIMARY KEY,
    Name    SYSNAME,
    Value   INT 
);
INSERT dbo.MyDemoTable (Name,Value)
SELECT o.name, o.object_id FROM sys.objects o;

CREATE INDEX IX_MyDemoTable_Value ON dbo.MyDemoTable(Value);

DECLARE @Reference INT;
SET @Reference = 28;

SELECT TOP(1) *
FROM (
    SELECT xx.Value FROM (SELECT TOP(1) x.Value FROM dbo.MyDemoTable x WHERE x.Value <= @Reference ORDER BY x.Value DESC) xx
    UNION ALL
    SELECT yy.Value FROM (SELECT TOP(1) x.Value FROM dbo.MyDemoTable x WHERE x.Value > @Reference ORDER BY x.Value ASC) yy
) z(Value)
ORDER BY ABS(z.Value - 28) ASC;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.MyDemoTable;
```

Output:

```
Value
-----------
28

Table 'MyDemoTable'. Scan count 2, logical reads 4
```

Execution plan:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (id INT, value INT)
INSERT INTO @t
VALUES 
(1,20),(2,30),(3,40),(4,50),(5,60),(6,70),(7,100)
```

**Query**

```
SELECT TOP 1 id  , Value, MIN(ABS(value - 28)) SmallestDiff
FROM @t 
GROUP BY id, Value
ORDER BY SmallestDiff
```

**Result**

```
╔════╦═══════╦══════════════╗
║ id ║ Value ║ SmallestDiff ║
╠════╬═══════╬══════════════╣
║  2 ║    30 ║            2 ║
╚════╩═══════╩══════════════╝
```